# Why isn't the compiler able to restrict the return type in this case

Tags: java

I have the following class:

```
Class Container<E extends Supertype>{
    ...
    public ArrayList<E> getList(){...}
    ...
}
```

However when I try to do this:

```
public void someFunction(Container x){
    ....
    for(Supertype s : x.getList()){
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

It gives a compile error saying the elements of `x.getList()` is of `Object`. However, since the elements must be of type `E` which must be a subclass of `Supertype`, why can't the compiler "work this out"?

My first thought was due to problems with raw types, but aren't those just the compiler being unsure whether something would be legal at run time?

---

Yes, I can do

```
public void someFunction(Container<?> x)
```

And it won't even give an unchecked warning when I pass a raw `Container`. Just trying the learn the quirks of Java here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is an issue with raw types. [When using a value of some raw type, any generics that are involved are erased.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8)

> The type of a constructor (§8.8), instance method (§8.4, §9.4), or
>   non-static field (§8.3) of a raw type `C` that is not inherited from its
>   superclasses or superinterfaces **is the raw type that corresponds to
>   the erasure of its type in the generic declaration corresponding to `C`.**

[The erasure of a generic type whose parameters have (or don't have) a bound is the type itself.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6)

> The erasure of a parameterized type (§4.5) `G<T1,...,Tn>` is `|G|`.

The following

```
public ArrayList<E> getList() {...}
```

becomes

```
public ArrayList getList() {...}
```

which makes `ArrayList#iterator()`

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {...}
```

become

```
public Iterator iterator() {...}
```

making `Iterator#next()`

```
public E next();
```

become

```
public Object next();
```